# Accessing attribute with argument from file.properties in Java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties-file

Let me explain what I want to do:

I got a properties containing a property like this:

```
message=Hello {0}, welcome.
```

I'd like to access this property in a Java class using a String and set the parameter in that class.

I've already use fmt:message and fmt:param to display this kind of property in a JSP but I want to manipulate it in a Java object now (I already know how to inject a property into the class).

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [java.util.ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) and [java.text.MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)
Some examples

```
private String getString( String bundle, String key, String defaultValue, Object... arguments ){
    String result = ResourceBundle.getBundle( bundle ).getString( key );
    if ( result == null ){
        result = defaultValue;
    }
    if ( arguments.length > 0 && result != null ){
        result = MessageFormat.format( result, arguments );
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: More details maybe? I'm already using the ResourceBundleMessageSource to access properties within .jsp files and use them with fmt. I really want to know how to access the property and set the parameter in Java.